# Using python-onvif, is there some way that I can get the text of error responses?

Tags: python-2.x, suds, python-onvif

I'm experimenting with the python-onvif library and command line client to work with a network camera I have.

When things are working it's fine, but in the event that I have an error, I get almost no useful information out of the thing.

For instance, if I use the wrong password to the cli, I end up with:

```
#onvif-cli devicemgmt GetCapabilities --host 192.168.0.149 -u admin -a wrongpw
False: Unknown error: (400, u'Bad Request')
```

That's the result of an Exception making it's way up from suds into python-onvif and being printed by the onvif-cli tool.

Tracing with wireshark shows that in fact the 400 response came back with a proper SOAP message indicating an auth failure.

A little debugging with pdb shows that the underlying 'suds' library seems to be simply eating that text and throwing the Exception. I attempted to use 'last_received()' in the suds client object to get the message, but it doesn't have the contents of the 400 - it has the last message the thing received correctly.

Is there any way for my code to get the contents of the 400 message? I'm happy to just get raw bytes - I just need something to log so that when things go bad in the field I can at least know what the camera thinks is happening.

I did try turning the 'faults' option to False in the creation of the suds.client.Client, but that just got me the (400, Bad Request) returned as a tuple - it still didn't decode the contents.

System is CentOS 6.6, suds version is 0.4, python-onvif 0.1.3, python 2.6.6, camera is a Sony EP580 with latest firmware.

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer. I faced the same issue and don't have any idea how to solve it. If you found the answer please help.

Comment: Sadly, I was unable to find an answer. Instead, I switched to writing my own client using the [gSOAP](https://www.genivia.com/dev.html) library. Once I figured out how to use the library I was able to make ONVIF calls pretty well, and it's easy enough to properly capture the error text.

Comment: Advice: Play with a utility like [Onvif Device Manager](https://sourceforge.net/p/onvifdm/wiki/Home/) to make sure that the ONVIF functions you want to use actually work correctly on the camera you have. It turns out that some camera manufacturers have some unpleasant shortcomings and bugs in their ONVIF implementations. If it doesn't work in ODM, it's probably because the CAMERA is screwing up, not ODM.